# PHP MySQL Ajax Live Search w/ MULTIPLE INPUTS

Tags: php, ajax

I have TWO inputs that will search the same database table. Using the code below, both inputs search correctly but both show the results div under the 1st input field.  I need the 2nd results div to appear under the 2nd input, not under the 1st. Hope this makes sense.

[image: Text in #dzip produces results in #ozip]

Search-Form.php:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("backend-search.php", {term1: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });

    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="tcalc" name="tcalc">
    <div class="search-box" style="white-space: nowrap;">

      <!-- Search origin zip /-->      
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="ozip" name="ozip" placeholder="Search Origin ZIPCode..." onclick="this.select();" autofocus />&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr>

      <!-- Search destination zip /-->      
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="dzip" name="dzip" placeholder="Search Destination ZIPCode..." onclick="this.select();"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr>                

      <!-- Dropdwon of results /-->               
        <div class="result">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>
    </form>                      
</body>
```

Backend-Search.php:

```
// Escape user inputs for security
$term = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['term']);

if(isset($term)){
    // Attempt select query execution if numeric
    if (is_numeric($term)) {
    $sql = "SELECT CONCAT(trim(zipcode),' | ',trim(pcity),', ',trim(state)) as 'result' from `tbl_uscomp_i` WHERE `zipcode` LIKE '" . $term . "%'"; 
    }
    // Attempt select query execution if alpha    
    if (ctype_alpha($term)) {
    $sql = "SELECT CONCAT(trim(zipcode),' | ',trim(pcity),', ',trim(state)) as 'result' from `tbl_uscomp_i` WHERE `pcity` LIKE '" . $term . "%'";     
        }        

    // Fetch results if results are indeed found  
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){     

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<p>" . $row['result'] . "</p>";
            }            
            // Close result set
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else {
            echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
        }
    } else {    
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

I also have a second question, as to how to allow input from the keybaord (arrows and enter/select) with the dropdown results  ...

Code is adapted from [here](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-ajax-live-search.php)

Comment: _"I don't know if the problem lies within the structure or the JavaScript variables"_ Find out! With your debugger.

Comment: Your JS handler is bound to multiple elements: `$('.search-box input[type="text"]')`. Inside that handler you grab the search term with `$(this).val();` which is returning two values.  Grab the search term by ID or name if you want them in separate variables.

Comment: Thanks EatPB, so, something like `$(#dzip).val();`  ???

Comment: Yes, more like`$('#dzip').val();`  (with the quotes around the selector)

Comment: How to get the 2nd results div to appear under the 2nd input, it still appears under the 1st... argh.  Do I create two scripts, one for each input?